# How to redirect to certian path using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect following url ...

```
www.example.com/test/test2/test3/file.html
```

to `www.example.com/change/file`
what would be the .htaccess file as i have less idea in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
# Start the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Assume the base is root and there are no alias
RewriteBase /
# Prevent loops if the directory exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Make sure there is an html file in the URL and capture it's filename if so.    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)\.html/?  [NC]
# Use only the filename as target directory.
RewriteRule .*  %1  [L,R=301]
```

Flags [L,R=301] mean is the last rule and it is a permanent redirection. Change to 302 if you want it to be temporal and remove the whole flag `R=301` if you want a silent mapping.

**UPDATED**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)\.html/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  change/%1  [R=301,L]

# Second rule set
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1/%1.html  [L]
```

Redirects permanently this

`http://www.example.com/test/test2/test3/file.html` to

`http://www.example.com/change/file`, with a silent map to

`http://www.example.com/change/file/file.html`

Comment: can you explain little more i do have less idea in it?

Comment: Sure. I will do it in the answer.

Comment: i tried your suggestion,and the output is, when it hit www.example.com/test/test2/test3/file.html its redirecting to www.example.com/file...i made a little mistake while asking question i have changed the question little bit..pls check the question.and also www.example.com/file gives 404 ,but i want to show the output of file.html in the folowing url www.example.com/change/file

Comment: I see your update. ¿It's `/change` a fixed name or it is a variable?

Comment: its a fixed name and can you say would this regexp would not effect anyplace

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22954/discussion-between-chanz-and-faa)

Comment: hi i have updated the htaccess in root folder but now nothing is happening

Comment: Try removing the first `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. It wasn't but I inserted it by mistake.

Comment: It is now redirecting properly ,but cannot get the html output.and addition to this its showing a This webpage has a redirect loop error

Comment: So it goes to `http://www.example.com/change/file` and shows that in the address bar, but then it displays the error. Right?

Comment: no i dont have any other htacess and my htacess file is placed in root folder

Comment: Please put the second rule set in my answer in one .htaccess file at `http://www.example.com/change/file` and try again, removing it from the root .htaccess file. It should work.

Comment: can you explain the last comment properly i am little confused

Comment: upvoted and selcted your answer...now i google how the regex work here